# Spark Connector with Cube js

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hive, cube, connector

I am working on a spark structured streaming project. I want to write  the results to cube so it can be accessible for front end development. I am aware that I can write the results to Postgresql or other databases and then integrate it with cube. But my question is that is there a way to directly integrate spark and cube. If no connector exists can there be a workaround?

I have done some research and found out that it is possible to integrate cube with Hive. So one possible way is to write my spark structured streaming results to hive and through hive to cube. But I am looking for a way to directly write the results to cube.